# How to do an mixed model ezANOVA

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I am relatively new to R, and would appreciate some assistance.

Let's say I have a new drug, and I am testing if it works.
I have Treatment A and B. Each person is treated with the drug on two separate  occasions and their response is recorded in several categories.
[image]

 
Now, lets say my dependent variable is Measurement 1 (M1), because all people received all levels of treatment (A or B) chosen at random, I know I am looking at a 1-way repeated Measures ANOVA.

Would I be correct in assuming that the following code captures my mixed model design?

mixed_eaov <- ezANOVA(data = HumanPop,
                  dv = M1,
                  wid = Person,
                  between = Treatment,
                  within = OrderofTreatment,
                  detailed = T)

When I go to run this data I get:
Warning: The column supplied as the wid variable contains non-unique values across levels of the supplied between-Ss variables. Automatically fixing this by generating unique wid labels.

Warning: Collapsing data to cell means first using variables supplied to "within_full", then collapsing the resulting means to means for the cells supplied to "within".

I then tried melting the data first with the d1 <- melt(HumanPop), which puts all variables M1-20 in one column called 'variable' and one called 'values' where the raw numbers are. However, I am unclear if this is correct, as I wish to analyse the differences between measurements as well.

If anyone knows how to help that would be much apprecaited